# How can I make my vertical bar tip to round in Flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile, responsive-design, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have this custom vertical bar in my card widget and I'm trying to make that vertical bar to little bit round at the top and the bottom like the design but I'm not sure how to do it so I would be really appreciated if I can get any help or suggestion. thanks

```
  Widget verticalBarSeparator(String value) {
    final int data = int.parse(value);
    return Container(
        color: data < 0 ? Colors.red : Colors.green, height: 80, width: 4);
  }
```

This is what I have so far
[image]

This is what I'm trying to do
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try this

```
Widget verticalBarSeparator(String value) {
  final int data = int.parse(value);
  return Container(
    height: 80, 
    width: 4,
    decoration: ShapeDecoration(
      color: data < 0 ? Colors.red : Colors.green,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: it work...thank you so much. I really appreciated it for your help.